# How to enable events scheduler on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to enable events scheduler on phpmyadmin (I'm using XAMPP on mac os) I get this error:

```
#1408 - Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to go php.ini file and search event_scheduler string and you need to change its value to On.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't find that string.

Comment: i did manage to add it to etc/my.conf and i still get the same error

Comment: For xamp this would be in below path.

Comment: Xamp/MySQL/bin/my.ini

Comment: event_scheduler has nothing to do with PHP, it has to do with mysql/mariadb database engines